# Ubuntu 21.04. new installation black screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics

I used Ubuntu for a while and after last "apt upgrade" the system won't boot. I tried to make clean install, which works OK, but once a perform update, the system won't boot again.

I get the GRUB menu and select Ubuntu, then I see computer logo for a while, then display turns black (No cursor, can't change TTY, nothing..). If I chose Ubuntu recovery mode, it's OK. System boots OK.

I think it's some graphics driver problem, but I don't know what to try. I have everything in default as it is new installation.

Does anyone have experienced same problem recently?

I have HP Omen laptop. Intel + Nvidia 1050M

I only tried to change Additional driver to Nvidia 460 from nouveau-xorg

Answer (score 2):

I'm running on Ubuntu 21.04 with GeForce GTX 570 and I had the same problem: After update I was stuck on black screen after graphical boot loading, but fortunately I could change to TTY3. In order to access system I had to run on recovery mode, but in order to do that I had to go to *root terminal*, then type `startx` and then type `exit` and select resume.

The issue is with driver graphic card. I have a version 390.143 and my solution was to download in **apt** drivers and lately to run installer downloaded from Nvidia website:

- Nvidia Drivers for 390: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/173111/en-us
- Page for other drivers: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Before installing make sure you have installed in system, package called `nvidia-driver-390`, if not and you don't have a repository, type

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
# apt update
# apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Next, in recovery mode enable network then open *root terminal*. If you have package `nvidia-driver-390` installed, then find a place, where you'll download in terminal another file. By default downloaded files are stored in `/root` directory. To download installer from Nvidia website in terminal type:

```
# wget https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.143/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.143.run
```

If you have a different version of driver, you can change that link for example for 418.113 drivers, the link is:

https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/418.113/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.113.run

As a template, the link looks like this:

```
https://*country*.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/*architecture*/*version*/NVIDIA-*architecture*-*version*.run
```

When you successfully downloaded this file, then you need to give permission in order to run installer, type:

```
# chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.143.run
# ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.143.run
```

Next, the window will appear, that'll looks like this:
[Start of NVIDIA installation process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVOHs.png)

Select **Continue installation**

If you'll get an information about driver that is already installed, select **Continue installation**. Next if it'll ask you about DKMS, choose default option, that is **No** and select to install 32-bit libraries (**Yes**). After successful install select marked options on the next pages, but in NVIDIA X configuration section, choose **Yes** and then reboot system. There may be some problems in configuring DKMS during installing process.

And now after rebooting, you should have a functioning system. This is my solution for repairing boot problem that worked for me.